# Excel: How to separate fraction parts by spaces every three digits?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can do this:

```
0.123456789
```

I want this:

```
0.123 456 789
```

How to achieve this?

(It works nice for me for leading numbers with the thousands separator but not for the fractions part with a space for grouping.)

Comment: You could set a custom format on the cell of 0.000 000 000

Comment: PS: sorry if i forgot to mention it - i was using Excel 2016. (might have some impact on the solution - but i did not notice any people mentioning any version specific needs variants related to versions during the current discussion.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Day,

Applying a custom number format should work for you. I tried ###.### ### ### and it worked. Please see the image below for an example.

[image]

Comment: I tried it out. Staying with the 9 trailing digit length from your example:
when opening the custom number format dialog option i got offered this: #.##0,000000000
when i were at the result that i roughly had in mind i had this: #.##0,000 000 000
i felt like i am selecting a fixed number of trailing digits -- i spotted no auto stop when only zeros will follow - i dont mind. Its fine for me in my limited duty.